# Are recv() and accept() interchangeable?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a socket that is set up to listen()

Normally I would accept() these connections based on a file descriptor being ready via select(). Can I change this to be a recv() instead of accept(), with that same file descriptor?

Comment: How exactly could a function that takes no arguments and returns a socket FD possibly be interchangeable with a function that takes buffer, length, etc arguments and returns a count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they're not interchangeable.

You're only listening on a single file descriptor using `select`, but you want have a file descriptor *per connection* once you have connected clients.

`accept` extracts the first connection request on the queue of pending connections for the listening socket, creates a new connected socket, and **returns a new file descriptor referring to that socket**.

Once you have that new file descriptor, you can use recv to receive data from the client on it.

Comment: Is the decriptor returned by accept modifiable? That is, can I set additional options on that socket to return additional info? I.E. I have a socket that is set up as SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_RAW - can I now set IPPROTO_IP options on the accept() socket to get things like the IP header?

Comment: @Derek Yes, you can use `setsockopt()` on the resulting file descriptor/socket, so I can't see why you'd not be able to get to the headers if it can be done on a SOCK_STREAM type socket at all (I've only seen it done on SOCK_RAW)

Comment: I think that may be the real problem. SOCK_STREAM is how the socket is set up. I dont think I can change that part - and it doesnt seem like there is a way to get that data once it has been stripped

Comment: @derek: You might like to open another question on whether accepted sockets are modifieable.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me to 'get it' is to realize that a socket set up to listen is used only for accepting connections (and never for sending data back and forth), while the file descriptor returned by accept() is used for sending data back and forth to one specific client (the one that did the connect) and has no use in interacting with any other client (including that it has no role in accepting connections from other clients). HTH.

Comment: Please see my comment on the other answer - Is the file descriptor returned by accept modifiable from the original socket?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You may be getting confused because recv(2) and read(2) are (mostly) interchangeable, but accept is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

accept() returns a pair (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to **send and receive** data on the connection, and address is the address bound to the socket on the other end of the connection.
In other words accept() forms a new socket (chooses a new port) to handle the request and using this new socket u are able to call recv() and send().